# MathJax (or something like it) as a classroom “blackboard”

Tags: mathematics-education

(I tried this first at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187265/mathjax-or-something-like-it-as-a-classroom-blackboard , but didn't get satisfactory responses.)

What is the best desktop application available now for running MathJax (or the equivalent) in the classroom?

I can't depend on having a connection to the web, so I'm seeking a stand-alone application. To be clear, I'd like to type as I talk and have the students see the typeset mathematics with as small a delay as possible.  At the end of my lecture I'd like to be able to export the notes in some reasonable elegant way.

---

Just today I experimented with Qute ( http://www.inkcode.net/qute ) - and found it barely adequate, though the lack of adjustable font sizes would make it illegible beyond the first few rows.

Comment: Have you considered some real-time compiling/preview version of (La)TeX? (This exists but I have no personal experience.) For details on this however the TeX stackexchange site seems best. (Not for MathJaX however).  

Comment: For real-time preview latex software, you might find some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311118/real-time-latex

Comment: I think that this is off-topic for this site (not sure where it would be on-topic; if you went for live *TeX* then that would be on-topic at tex.stackexchange.com but if you insist on live *MathJaX* then you're more into programming or servers.  In fact, what's stopping you setting up a web server on your computer and viewing a MathJaX page on localhost?).  However, even more I think this is a bad idea.  The danger is that you'll spend too much time concentrating on getting the maths to look nice and the students will get distracted.